# KARATE, VScode : "Run Karate Test" codelens not displayed

Tags: visual-studio-code, karate, codelens

Visual Studio Code 1.43.0
Karate Standalone JAR 0.9.5.RC5

In the VScode editor, in a Karate .feature file opened, the codelens "Run Karate Test", as shown in the screenshot, isn't displayed anymore.
So, it is impossible to debug a specific scenario.
Any idea about this?
Thanks a lot.

[image]

In a correct configuration, it looks like this :
[image]

Comment: Do you have a project you can post somewhere that reproduces this.  Haven't heard of anyone having this problem.  I just verified several projects, Maven, Gradle and the Karate Jar and they all work.

Answer (score 1):

We are still unable to reproduce this issue.  Referencing some searches it appears this may be due to a broader issue such as other plugins Eg. Intellisense.  Reference to the broader issues https://www.google.com/search?q=vscode+codelens+not+showing

I would recommend trying a clean install with only the Karate Plugin to do some process of elimination.  The latest Karate Version is 0.8.1 by the way which it doesn't appear you are using.  The Codelens names have changed recently to "Karate: Run" and "Karate: Debug".

Hope this helps.