# Run Karate Test / Debug option not displayed

Tags: karate

Visual Studio Code 1.43.0 and karate-0.9.6.RC1.zip (Have also tried 0.9.5.zip)

In VSCode editor, in a Karate .feature file opened, the codelens "Run Karate Test" is still not getting displayed. Have explored all options of disabling extensions, still no luck. Please guide if someone has a solution to it.

Opened demo project folder karate-0.9.6.RC1 in visual code and tried to run src\demo\web\google.feature. (Tried API/Mock feature files as well). Not able to find "Run Karate Test" codelens

Below is the link of the demo project to download karate-0.9.6.RC1.zip:
https://dl.bintray.com/ptrthomas/karate/

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWudz.png]

Comment: i tried both versions of karate with the latest version of vscode 1.44.1 and codelens "Run Karate Test" always displays.  can you try the latest version.  if still an issue can you do two things 1) send your list of installed extensions by running "code --list-extensions" from the command line and 2) try reopening vscode in verbose/debug mode from the command line and try opening a feature file again by running "code --verbose --log debug".  after "Run Karate Tests" fails to load again capture all of the output from the command line and send.

Comment: Thanks @CaptainKirk... late reply as i was not keeping well. 
Below are the extensions installed:
C:\Users\SGyaneshwar>code --list-extensions
alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete
Blodwynn.featurehighlight
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
deerawan.vscode-protractor-snippets
kirkslota.karate-runner
redhat.java
stevejpurves.cucumber
VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode
vscjava.vscode-java-debug
vscjava.vscode-java-dependency
vscjava.vscode-java-pack
vscjava.vscode-java-test
vscjava.vscode-maven

Comment: refer 4/28 update for the VS code verbose log in the updated question details at the end. Thanks

Comment: thank you for the update.  can you try the suggestions i posted here to do some process of elimination.  start with no extensions and a clean install of the latest VSCode.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60651255/karate-vscode-run-karate-test-codelens-not-displayed?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

1. Extensions:

   ```
   C:\Users\SGyaneshwar>code --list-extensions
   ```

   alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete
   Blodwynn.featurehighlight
   dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
   deerawan.vscode-protractor-snippets
   kirkslota.karate-runner
   redhat.java
   stevejpurves.cucumber
   VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode
   vscjava.vscode-java-debug
   vscjava.vscode-java-dependency
   vscjava.vscode-java-pack
   vscjava.vscode-java-test
   vscjava.vscode-maven

   2. Verbose log post launching the feature file not showing Karate Run option:

   C:\Users\SGyaneshwar>code --verbose --log debug

   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.302Z] Starting VS Code
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.302Z] from: c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.302Z] args: {
     _: [],
     diff: false,
     add: false,
     goto: false,
     'new-window': false,
     'reuse-window': false,
     wait: false,
     help: false,
     'list-extensions': false,
     'show-versions': false,
     version: false,
     verbose: true,
     log: 'debug',
     status: false,
     'prof-startup': false,
     'disable-extensions': false,
     'disable-gpu': false,
     telemetry: false,
     logExtensionHostCommunication: false,
     'skip-getting-started': false,
     'skip-release-notes': false,
     'sticky-quickinput': false,
     'disable-restore-windows': false,
     'disable-telemetry': false,
     'disable-updates': false,
     'disable-crash-reporter': false,
     'disable-user-env-probe': false,
     'skip-add-to-recently-opened': false,
     'unity-launch': false,
     'open-url': false,
     'file-write': false,
     'file-chmod': false,
     'driver-verbose': false,
     force: false,
     trace: false,
     'force-user-env': false,
     'no-proxy-server': false,
     nolazy: false,
     'force-renderer-accessibility': false,
     'ignore-certificate-errors': false,
     'allow-insecure-localhost': false
   }
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.304Z] Resolving machine identifier...
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.304Z] Resolved machine identifier: e1f17697e9bdf600c8a6f6d42df65a7547708110e2ce335c2ff426197ae02411 (trueMachineId: undefined)
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.335Z] [storage state.vscdb] open(c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\state.vscdb, retryOnBusy: true)
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.336Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 2)
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.337Z] windowsManager#open
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.338Z] window#validateWindowState: validating window state on 1 display(s) { mode: 0, x: 0, y: 0, width: 1536, height: 824 }
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.339Z] window#validateWindowState: 1 monitor working area { x: 0, y: 0, width: 1536, height: 824 }
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.339Z] window#ctor: using window state { mode: 0, x: 0, y: 0, width: 1536, height: 824 }
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.415Z] lifecycle (main): phase changed (value: 3)
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.416Z] update#setState idle
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.417Z] telemetry/optInStatus { optIn: true }
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.417Z] telemetry/update:win32SetupTarget { target: 'system' }
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.418Z] telemetry/machineIdFallback { usingFallbackGuid: false }
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.627Z] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): SELECT * FROM ItemTable
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.630Z] [storage state.vscdb] getItems(): 74 rows
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.732Z] [storage state.vscdb] updateItems(): insert(Map(3) {storage.serviceMachineId => dc3fde25-5712-4a8e-ad3b-c62e2668be86, telemetry.lastSessionDate => Wed, 22 Apr 2020 06:18:38 GMT, telemetry.currentSessionDate => Wed, 22 Apr 2020 06:20:28 GMT}), delete(Set(0) {})
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.735Z] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): BEGIN TRANSACTION
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.736Z] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): INSERT INTO ItemTable VALUES ('storage.serviceMachineId','dc3fde25-5712-4a8e-ad3b-c62e2668be86'),('telemetry.lastSessionDate','Wed, 22 Apr 2020 06:18:38 GMT'),('telemetry.currentSessionDate','Wed, 22 Apr 2020 06:20:28 GMT')
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.739Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.742Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.742Z] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): END TRANSACTION
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:28.943Z] [File Watcher (node.js)] >> normalized [CHANGED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:29.917Z] getShellEnvironment: running on Windows, skipping
   [32284:0422/115030.611:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] open(c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\1587536373179\state.vscdb, retryOnBusy: true)", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115030.639:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): PRAGMA user_version = 1;", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115030.651:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ItemTable (key TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE, value BLOB)", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115030.666:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] getItems(): 7 rows", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115030.667:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): SELECT * FROM ItemTable", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115030.670:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 lifecycle: starting up (startup kind: 1)", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115030.670:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 lifecycle: phase changed (value: 2)", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115030.979:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 workbench configuration {"_":[],"verbose":true,"log":"debug","appRoot":"c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app","machineId":"e1f17697e9bdf600c8a6f6d42df65a7547708110e2ce335c2ff426197ae02411","nodeCachedDataDir":"C:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\CachedData\a9f8623ec050e5f0b44cc8ce8204a1455884749f","mainPid":32284,"execPath":"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe","userEnv":{"VSCODE_IPC_HOOK":"\\.\pipe\aaf90cbd3d6d9a1a9a4eef6af2183c80-1.44.1-main-sock","VSCODE_NLS_CONFIG":"{\"locale\":\"en-us\",\"availableLanguages\":{},\"_languagePackSupport\":true}","VSCODE_LOGS":"C:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028"},"isInitialStartup":true,"backupPath":"c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\Backups\1587536373179","windowId":1,"sessionId":"window:1","logLevel":0,"zoomLevel":1,"maximized":true,"perfEntries":["main:started",1587536428116,"main:appReady",1587536428230,"willLoadMainBundle",1587536428234,"didLoadMainBundle",1587536428291,"main:loadWindow",1587536428397],"partsSplashPath":"C:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\rapid_render.json","backupWorkspaceResource":{"$mid":1,"path":"/C:/Users/SGyaneshwar/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/Backups/1587536373179","scheme":"vscode-userdata"}}", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:30.981Z] IPC#vscode-workbenchReady
   [32284:0422/115031.021:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 lifecycle: phase changed (value: 3)", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115031.072:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/optInStatus [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115031.073:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/activatePlugin [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115031.073:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/keyboardLayout [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115031.073:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/textmodelresolveruri [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115031.073:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/workspaceLoad [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115031.074:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/machineIdFallback [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:31.699Z] ElectronMainService#crashReporter {"companyName":"Microsoft","productName":"VSCode","submitURL":"appcenter://code?aid=4bb700cb-399a-49a4-9322-3a28c277609b&uid=7d588a7b-6273-4343-9f47-5e71afb22866&iid=7d588a7b-6273-4343-9f47-5e71afb22866&sid=963b9c48-000a-426a-838c-c2d108c3a4a51587536430672","extra":{"vscode_version":"1.44.1","vscode_commit":"a9f8623ec050e5f0b44cc8ce8204a1455884749f","_productName":"VSCode","_companyName":"Microsoft","_version":"1.44.1"}}
   [32284:0422/115031.700:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] updateItems(): insert(Map(0) {}), delete(Set(1) {lifecyle.lastShutdownReason})", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115031.775:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): BEGIN TRANSACTION", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115031.804:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): DELETE FROM ItemTable WHERE key IN ('lifecyle.lastShutdownReason')", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115031.935:INFO:CONSOLE(355)] "Overwriting extension <<.feature>> to now point to mime <>", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (355)
   [32284:0422/115031.935:INFO:CONSOLE(355)] "Overwriting extension <<.feature>> to now point to mime <>", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (355)
   [32284:0422/115031.935:INFO:CONSOLE(355)] "Overwriting extension <<.feature>> to now point to mime <>", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (355)
   [32284:0422/115031.986:INFO:CONSOLE(4414)] "Overwriting grammar scope name to file mapping for scope text.gherkin.feature.
   Old grammar file: file:///c%3A/Users/SGyaneshwar/.vscode/extensions/alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete-2.14.1/syntaxes/feature.tmLanguage.
   New grammar file: file:///c%3A/Users/SGyaneshwar/.vscode/extensions/stevejpurves.cucumber-0.12.0/syntaxes/feature.tmLanguage", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (4414)
   [32284:0422/115032.038:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): END TRANSACTION", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115032.043:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\output_1_20200422T115030", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115032.055:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\output_1_20200422T115030", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115032.104:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/activatePlugin [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115032.257:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] >> normalized [CHANGED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\output_1_20200422T115030", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:32.701Z] Shared process: IPC ready
   [32284:0422/115032.867:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] [ADDED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\exthost1", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115032.870:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\exthost1", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115032.871:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] [ADDED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\sharedprocess.log", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.044:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/activatePlugin [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.044:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/activatePlugin [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.044:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/activatePlugin [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.045:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/activatePlugin [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.045:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/activatePlugin [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.045:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/activatePlugin [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.045:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/activatePlugin [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.045:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/activatePlugin [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.046:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/activatePlugin [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.049:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\exthost1", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.105:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 MainThreadTreeViews#$registerTreeViewDataProvider karate-reports [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.105:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 MainThreadTreeViews#$registerTreeViewDataProvider karate-tests [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.105:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 MainThreadTreeViews#$refresh karate-reports undefined", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.105:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 MainThreadTreeViews#$refresh karate-tests undefined", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.122:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/extensionActivationTimes [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.122:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/extensionActivationTimes [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.122:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/extensionActivationTimes [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.123:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/extensionActivationTimes [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.123:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/extensionActivationTimes [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.123:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/extensionActivationTimes [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.130:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\exthost1", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.139:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/extensionActivationTimes [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.139:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/extensionActivationTimes [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.160:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] [ADDED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\git.txt", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.362:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] >> normalized [ADDED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\exthost1", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.362:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] >> normalized [ADDED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\sharedprocess.log", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.362:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] >> normalized [ADDED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\git.txt", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.522:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 lifecycle: phase changed (value: 4)", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.524:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 RequestService#request https://vscodeexperiments.azureedge.net/experiments/vscode-experiments.json", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.590:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/windowsEdition [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.593:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/workspce.tags [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.597:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/startupRawTimers [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.597:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/resolveProxy.stats [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:33.609Z] RequestService#request https://update.code.visualstudio.com/api/update/win32-x64/stable/a9f8623ec050e5f0b44cc8ce8204a1455884749f
   [32284:0422/115033.644:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/experiments [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:33.649Z] Shared process: init ready
   [32284:0422/115033.804:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] [ADDED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\telemetry.log", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.804:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\telemetry.log", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.813:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] [ADDED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\userDataSync.log", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.968:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 CommandService#executeCommand setContext", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.981:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 MainThreadTimeline#registerTimelineProvider: id=git-history", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.981:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 TimelineService#registerTimelineProvider: id=git-history", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115033.986:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/extensionActivationTimes [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115034.014:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] >> normalized [ADDED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\telemetry.log", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115034.014:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] >> normalized [ADDED] c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\20200422T115028\userDataSync.log", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115034.165:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/galleryService:query [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115034.165:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 RequestService#request https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/extensionquery", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115034.422:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 telemetry/startupTimeVaried [object Object]", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:44.298Z] windowsManager#open
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:44.301Z] Lifecycle#unload() - window ID 1
   [32284:0422/115044.333:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 lifecycle: onBeforeUnload (reason: 4)", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115044.333:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 lifecycle: onBeforeUnload continues without veto", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [main 2020-04-22T06:20:44.333Z] Lifecycle#unload() - no veto (window ID 1)
   [32284:0422/115044.335:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 lifecycle: onWillUnload (reason: 4)", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115044.341:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] updateItems(): insert(Map(1) {lifecyle.lastShutdownReason => 4}), delete(Set(0) {})", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115044.342:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): BEGIN TRANSACTION", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115044.343:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): INSERT INTO ItemTable VALUES ('lifecyle.lastShutdownReason','4')", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115044.346:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): END TRANSACTION", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115044.353:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] close()", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115045.576:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] open(c:\Users\SGyaneshwar\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\b6bca6d1064a98dc20334f9740995e5a\state.vscdb, retryOnBusy: true)", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115045.618:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): PRAGMA user_version = 1;", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115045.618:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ItemTable (key TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE, value BLOB)", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)
   [32284:0422/115045.636:INFO:CONSOLE(1611)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): SELECT * FROM ItemTable", source: file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (1611)